# How to find recursivley log of base 10 in c++

Tags: c++

I have just started learning recursive functions and I'm looking for recursive way to find log of base 10 , I have figured out the iterative way which is following:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i=1,number,c=0;

    cout<<"Enter a number whose log is to be calculated"<<endl;
    cin>>number;

    while(i!=number){
         i=i*10;
         c++;
    }
    cout<<"The log is"<<c<<endl;
    system("pause");                 

}
```

Now for the recursive function should be the base case like:

```
if (number==10)
return 1;
else ??
```

I cannot really think of the recursive function please help me

Comment: Your function isn't very good - it will never stop for most numbers.

Comment: Read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series[Lg[x]%2C{x%2C0%2CInfinity}]

Comment: My question is to simple calculate the log of base 10; For 
example, 
log (base 10) of 100 = 2 
log (base 10) of 1000 = 3 
log (base 10) of 10000 = 4 and so on. 
How we have calculated log? It‟s very simple for the whole powers of "base" of log. 
Keep multiplying the base with itself inside a loop until it is equal to the given number. 
so dasblinkenlight for which number my function will never stop?

Comment: oh you're talking about recursive function? i know but i cannot think of anything better please help me develope a base and recursive case for given code

Comment: @Fatima: Your function will not terminate if the input is not of the form _10^n_ with an integer _n_.

Comment: okay thankyou i changed my base case and now im considering it if(num is negative) stop the function

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea of recursion is to solve a problem you cannot solve directly by repeatedly reducing it to smaller problems you can solve directly.

To illustrate this, take Fibonacci numbers, defined as following:

- f(0) = 0
- f(1) = 1
- f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)

Using this definition, you cannot get all Fibonacci numbers directly, only the Fibonacci numbers for n=0 and n=1. For calculating the Fibonacci number for n=2, you do the following:

- f(2) = f(2-1)+f(2-2) = 1+0 = 1

For n=3:

- f(3) = f(3-1)+f(3-2) = f(2-1)+f(2-2)+1 = 1+0+1 = 2

and so on.

For your problem, you know that

- log10(10) = 1

and you use the fact that

- log10(10*x) = log10(10)+log10(x) = 1+log10(x)

That is your recursion function.

---

NB: Using this definition, you assume that your input x is of the form 10^n with integer n, otherwise, you will not reach the case log10(10)!

Comment: thank you !! i figured out another solution but cannot find it useful for 10002 like inputs heres my code # include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//int log_10(int,int);
int log_10(int num, int count = -1)
{
 if (num)
 {
  num = (num/10);
  count++;

  return (log_10(num,count) );
 
 }
 else return count; 
}

int main()
{
    int num;
 cout<<"Enter a number whose log is to be calculated"<<endl;
 cin>>num;

 int result = log_10 (num);
 
    cout<<result;
system ("pause");
}